# Angular 2 typescript vscode import path suddenly disappeared

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I upgrade the VSCode and now when I press Ctrl + dot to import namespace, I now get paths like

```
import { Store } from '../../../../node_modules/@ngrx/store';
```

instead of

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
```

This was not happening before but suddenly now all of them are showing like this.

Answer (score 0):

I already faced the same issue, and its an issue with the latest release. Please check the following reported issue from **[`here`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54254)**

anyway VsCode team says its a duplicate of [`this`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54254), we might have to wait until get resolved.